# Is there a command line compiler for .jrxml files?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to find a way to quickly compile a large batch of .jrxml files to .jasper files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use Ant, but this should do what you want: 
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/antcompile/

Answer (score 2):

JasperStarter can compile all reports in a directory:

- http://jasperstarter.sourceforge.net